# Algorithm to calculate the real jordan decomposition of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

I have recently implemented the QR algorithm to determine the eigenvalues of a real matrix. Then, using the approax descibed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947108/how-to-get-eigenvectors-using-qr-algorithm), I've calculated the eigenvectors of this matrix. So, from this algorithms I can diagonalize a real matrix, if it has only real and non-repeated eigenvalues. Hovewer, I'd like to determine a more generic decomposition, such as the [Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). How could I do that? Is there any algorithms to do this decomposition in generic real matrices?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322755/jordan-form-step-by-step-general-algorithm) help ?

Comment: @KurtG. I'm actually looking for an algorithm that a computer can use to determine jordan's decomposition. In my view this algorithm is a procedure that serves to teach people how to find the jordan decomposition

Comment: I don't have code that your computer could use. If this algorthim properly teaches people how to find the Jordan decomposition it should be possible to write some code that follows those steps. MSE is about maths. Not a code repository.